# Find the count of multiple occurrences of a row using Cypher queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I returned the following rows:

```
 n.stype p.stype
   ["d"]    ["s","dr"]      
   ["d"]    ["s","dr"]      
   ["p"]    ["s","dr"]
   ["p"]    ["s","dr"]
   ["p"]    ["s","dr"]
   ["p"]    ["dr"]
   ["p"]    ["dr"]      
   ["d"]    ["s"]       
   ["d"]    ["dr"]  
   ["d"]    ["dr"]
```

With the following match query:

```
MATCH (n:data)-[r: related]->(p: data) return n.stype, t.stype
```

how can I modify this query to return the count of the occurrences of each distinct rows:

```
n.stype p.stype    count
["d"]   ["s","dr"]  2   
["p"]   ["s","dr"]  3
["p"]   ["dr"]      2
["d"]   ["s"]       1   
["d"]   ["dr"]      2
```

Comment: You have a variable "t" in there that isn't in the pattern...was that meant to be "p"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the COUNT() function. This introduces an aggregation (a group by), where the non-aggregation columns returned act as the grouping key.

```
MATCH (n:data)-[r: related]->(p:data) 
RETURN n.stype, p.stype, COUNT(p.stype) as count
```

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept the answer when you get the chance. Also helpful to read up on [aggregations](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-aggregation) in the Neo4j developers manual.